# Replacing all ampersand with paragraph if there is no backslash infront of it

Tags: regex

Is it possible to more precisely specify, what I want to have replaced?
I am trying to achieve replacing all '&' with '§' unless there is a '\' in front of the '&'. How would that be done? An explanation of how exactly the function works would do it as well. I have tried using a simple while loop, that goes through all the characters, but that seemed a bit too time-consuming.

For example: &eMe \& &bYou -> §eMe & §bYou

So if someone would be able to explain, how exactly one can do this, I would be very thankful.

Comment: Downvoted for lack of attempt and prior research.

Comment: Okay! I agree with you!

Comment: Probably would be a good idea to list some test text and the desired outcome.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Code

[See regex in use here](https://regex101.com/r/oegV62/1)

```
(?<!\\)&
```

Replacement: `§`

#### Usage

[See code in use here](https://ideone.com/iTuL4H): Part of code [autogenerated by regex101](https://regex101.com/r/oegV62/1/codegen?language=java)

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

/* Name of the class has to be "Main" only if the class is public. */
class Ideone
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        final String regex = "(?<!\\\\)&";
        final String string = "&&&&&\\&\\&\\&&&&";
        final String subst = "§";

        final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
        final Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(string);

        // The substituted value will be contained in the result variable
        final String result = matcher.replaceAll(subst);

        System.out.println("Substitution result: " + result);
    }
}
```

---

### Explanation

- `(?<!\\)` Negative lookbehind ensuring what precedes does not match
- `&` Match this literally

Comment: Thank you very much! This works excellently!